# the exact meaning of the clause "По согласованию Сторон"

Tags: значения

For the context, this is the reference text:

> По согласованию Сторон будет обеспечено строительство новых
> транспортных коммуникаций, связывающих Нахичеванскую Автономную
> Республику с западными районами Азербайджана.

(from http://www.kremlin.ru/events/president/news/64384)

In the English version of the page, this paragraph reads:

> As agreed by the Parties, new transport links shall be built to
> connect the Nakhchivan Autonomous Republic and the western regions of
> Azerbaijan.

(from http://en.kremlin.ru/events/president/news/64384)

Now, I suspect that the first clause in the Russian sentence might be better translated as "By agreement of the Parties", or something along these lines; that is, as opposed to what the above English version suggests, I suspect that the agreement in question doesn't already exist, but rather what comes next is conditioned upon such an agreement in the future.

Can anyone please tell me if I'm right or if the original English translation is (more) accurate?

Comment: @YellowSky The preposition *по* in the sense *after* is normally used with Prepositional case (*по прошествии, по окончании*). When used with Dative, it clearly means *by* or *according to*.

Comment: @J-mster -Right you are, my fault...

Comment: The deverbal noun _согласование_ names the process, ‘agreeing’, while ‘agreement’ is the result or even a legal act, or even a written document, or can be understood as such. _Согласование_ is just ‘agreeing’, so the English version of the page is correct in this respect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with the OP, the English translation is wrong. I would say, по согласованию сторон is even less definite than "by agreement". I would translate it "if the sides agree" or "according to an expected future agreement between the sides".

Also, Russian согласование usually does not mean agreement, but discussion, negotiation (agreement would be согласие, not согласование). So, the phrase can be translated "after a future negotiation" or "according to the results of a future negotiation".

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your helpful answer! As it's obvious, your explanation kind of approves my own impression, so I think I might be a bit biased towards yours. Moreover, the other answers are (explicitly) contradicting it. So tbh, I'm really confused now. :) Can I possibly conclude that, absent additional information, the text is essentially ambiguous? I would appreciate any further comment, esp. considering the other conflicting answers.

Comment: @Âloh no, it is not ambiguous, it is actually a common phrase, meaning "pending further negotiation". Basically, согласование simply does not mean "agreement", it means "negotiation".

Comment: @Âloh based on the context, it may mean the construction is to be conducted anyway, but the details are still unclear.

Comment: Thanks so much, again, for your attention and further clarification! Best!

Answer (score 1):

For me as a native Russian 'По согласованию сторон' means exactly 'As agreed'. It's a stable phrase, no need to analyze it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer! So, in your opinion, there's no ambiguity whatsoever in that according to the text, the agreement in question ALREADY EXISTS; is that right?

Answer (score 1):

According to the agreement in question [tripartite], which was arrived at **in November 2020**, Russia as well as Turkey, Armenia and Iran can take advantage of the new transport corridor between Nakhichevan and the western regions of Azerbaijan, which is due to be laid out within the next three years. According to the agreement Armenia will be warranting its safety.

And that is why the given translation is absolutely expedient: "***As agreed*** [in November 2020] ***by the Parties***, new transport links shall be built to connect the Nakhchivan Autonomous Republic and the western regions of Azerbaijan."

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the agreement in question does not exist or is not final. It will be negotiated and made while building the new transport connections. And the original English translation is not so accurate in this regard.

"По согласованию Сторон" - "By agreement of the Parties"